# To merge Two identical tables in PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables.
T1

```
1|A
2|B
3|C
```

T2

```
1|D
2|E
3|F
```

I need to merge T2 to T1, resulting in

T1

```
1|A
2|B
3|C
4|D
5|E
6|F
```

what will be the query for this?

I tried
INSERT INTO T1 SELECT * FROM T2
but it ended up like

T1

```
1|A
2|B
3|C
1|D
2|E
3|F
```

which is not the required output.

Comment: you want to generate the number like identity when you merged ?

Comment: What if t1 contained 7,8,9  and t2 contained 100,300,500?